# How to make data type "real" shorter in Pascal

Tags: types, numbers, pascal

My program transfers millimeters to meters and centimeters. And it is working, but answer is like 1,394900000000000000... How to make it shorter?

```
Program radiuss;
var 

mill : real;
metr : real;
cent : real;

Begin
Writeln('Сколько миллиметов надо перевести?');
Readln(mill);

metr := mill * 0.001;
cent := mill * 0.1;

Writeln('Метры:', metr);
Writeln('Сантиметры:', cent);

End.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may specify how many digits of fraction part do you want to print in the `writeln`s. Here is example of how to print 3 and 1 digits respectively:

```
Writeln('Метры:', metr:0:3);
Writeln('Сантиметры:', cent:0:1);
```